# Convert QT/C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, qt

This might seem a little ridiculous, but as some of you here may already know, I'm converting an application written in C++ to C#.

I've noticed that a lot of the code uses references to objects like "QObject", "QWidget", or "QFrame."

Because of this, I'm not quite sure if I should look up the source for QT and port the basic structure of that into a bunch of C# classes which essentially mimic the same functionality, or if there's any kind of framework out there which does the same thing and can be used as a replacement for this.

Also, could someone please explain to me what a slide and a slot is, and what it is I could do to mimic this in C# as well? I'm thinking delegates, but I'm not sure...

Comment: So you are going to reimplement the entire, gigantic QT framework, about which you seem to know almost nothing? Isn't this obviously insane?

Comment: port QT to C#... that would be interesting :)))) if they already have ports to js or python - why not c# :)))

Comment: There are QT bindings to .NET - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(framework)#Use_of_native_UI-rendering_APIs

Comment: well... then he may use them, and all would be much easier

Comment: Are you porting it to Windows Forms or WPF or something else? I expect they'd have a lot of the same concepts (QWidget = [System.Windows.Forms.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) or [System.Windows.Controls.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx), say, or one of their close relatives). I suspect your best bet would be to figure out how the current UI works then redevelop it in WPF or forms, and port only the business logic behind the UI.

Comment: I would say Windows Forms sounds like my best bet then. I really know nothing about GUI, this is my first real app and I've been programming C# for like 2 months now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Qyoto](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Qyoto) it might just drop in to you code with a few modifications.

Comment: Don't I have to have Mono and Linux to use that though? I like Linux, but Mono in comparison to VS (unfortunately, I might add) is relatively bad: I tried using one of my project files in it and the file actually broke. : /

Comment: The alternative would be to develop the equivalent of Qyoto yourself. Getting a build environment to work is easy in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The page that Oded recommended also gave a link to [qt4dotnet](http://code.google.com/p/qt4dotnet/) - have you tried this?

If you can't use one of these bindings, you will probably want to start investigating how to port all Q* references in the codebase to WinForms, WPF, or Silverlight (depending on your application needs)

Comment: I actually haven't tried that, but I think I may just end up porting to WinForms or WPF. Thanks.